# Save Web-based InfoPath form with the title as its file name

Tags: infopath, form

How do I save a new web-based InfoPath form without having to manual-type the file name in the Save As dialog box as shown below:

[image]

The 'Name' column, which represent the File name can be derive from other column of the form. (Assuming all column of the forms need to be filled up).

**Example**: 
In the form, there are 3 column named - Book_Title, Book_Author, Book_Price.
When a user create a new item in the form and provide the following information:
Book_Title: JQuery 
Book_Author: Anderson 
Book_Price: USD 10 
After the user have typed finish, the user click save and SharePoint immediately name the File name as "JQuery_Anderson" and auto-close the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding custom save/submit button to your form.

- [Custom Save Button for Web Enabled Form](http://blogs.microlinkllc.com/dmcwee/archive/2009/04/30/custom-save-button-for-web-enabled-form.aspx)
- [Custom Save and Submit Buttons for InfoPath Browser Forms](http://markhaverty.com/sharepoint/custom-save-and-submit-buttons-for-infopath-browser-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a workflow after the fact, build a dynamic string storing Book Title and underscore and the Book Author.  Then update the title with that value.